# How to count that how many time an item from my web site is being downloaded

Tags: php

There are differnt types of items available on my site to downlaod for exnample audio video data,pdf files.,doc files. when a user going to click th download button there will be a message is displayed that tells the user that how many time this item is already been downloaded.a TABLE with name of tbldownload having fields download_id(primary key)   download_item_id    download_type   download_date is there. and i am using this function to count.

```
function getTND($id)
{
    $query = "select * from tbldownload where download_item_id= '$id'";
    $rs = mysql_query($query);  
    while($row = mysql_num_rows($rs))
         return count($id);
}
```

Comment: Either use the return value of the num_rows function, or get the query to return the count as in Joey's answer. But I should state here that `mysql_*` should no longer be used as it's deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: Using `mysql_num_rows` is a very bad idea. Yo are getting all the data from table when you need only the number of items, use `COUNT` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should return a count of all the items based on your where clause.

```
"SELECT count(download_item_id) FROM tbldownload WHERE download_item_id = '$id'";
```